# Forms Authentication. Get allowed verb for a role specified in web.config

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, http-verbs

I've specified verbs for roles in web.config. This works fine, the role observer is redirected to login page if the role tries to post in page Test.aspx. Example:

```
  <location path="Test1.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrator" />
        <allow roles="Observer" verbs="GET" />
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Test2.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrator" />
        <allow roles="Observer" />
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

But this is a bit confusing for the user when trying to POST in page Test.aspx. I want to inform the user that he/she is not allowed to post before actually clicking anything. Something like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If *Not User.Role("Observer").Verbs("Post").Allowed* then
       uiSave.enabled = false
    End if
End Sub
```

So, the question is: Where can I access this information?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if(User.IsInRole("Observer")){
 //code here
}
```

[Example here](https://media.sdn.sap.com/html/submitted_docs/dotnet/How%20to/User.IsInRole%20Method.htm)

You wont need to check the Verb because you already know that users in the Observer role do not permission to usethe Post verb

Comment: Ah, but I will have roles who have full access to some pages and only GET access to some.

Comment: Updated to original question to explain better

Comment: Mmm, OOB i dont think there is a way. You may have to write your own logic on that one.